# Does the api_code of Blockchain.info's Create Wallet API expire?

Tags: blockchain.info, api

Does the api_code of Blockchain.info's Create Wallet API expire?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing on the [Blockchain Wallet API information](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api) page or the [API signup page](https://api.blockchain.info/customer/signup) to suggest that the key would expire, so I would imagine it does not.